# Change background-color upon click (using map function in javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a menu of buttons and upon hover over, they change in background-color. Below is a toy version. (Context: I use a map function because the number, names, and colors of buttons are dependent on the elements in "myList" and "myColors" which can be different in other cases.)

However, when the user clicks on a button, I'd like the button to stay that color. All clicked button should remain colored, so multiple buttons can stay colored at the same time. But when the user clicks "done", all the buttons should return to white/transparent. Does anyone know how to do this?

I'm having trouble making this edit since I create the button ids with a mapping function, which means I can't directly edit the background colors in my css file.

Many thanks in advance!

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style media="screen">
      .buttons {
        width: 150px;
        height: 50px;
        border: solid 2px black;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: white;
        margin: 2px;
      }

      #buttonGallery {
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: solid 2px black;
        width: 155px;
      }

      #done {
        width: 150px;
        height: 50px;
        border: solid 2px black;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: white;
        margin: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="done">
      <p>done</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      let $buttons = $('<div id="buttonGallery">');
      let myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
      let myColors = ["red", "green", "blue", "red"];

      myList.map(function (letter, index) {
        let $button = $("<div></div>")
          .addClass("buttons")
          .attr("id", "button_" + letter)
          .html("<p>" + letter + "</p>")
          .on("mouseenter", function () {
            $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
          })
          .on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(this).css("background", "transparent");
          });
        $buttons.append($button);
      });

      $("body").append($buttons);

      $("#done").on("click", clearColor);

      function clearColor() {
        //change background-color of all buttons to white/transparent
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to add an additional class to buttons once they are clicked to keep the hover functionality.

```
let $buttons = $('<div id="buttonGallery">');
      let myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
      let myColors = ["red", "green", "blue", "red"];

      myList.map(function (letter, index) {
        let $button = $("<div></div>")
          .addClass("buttons")
          .attr("id", "button_" + letter)
          .html("<p>" + letter + "</p>")
          .on("mouseenter", function () {
            $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
          })
          .on("mouseleave", function () {
                    if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
            $(this).css("background", "transparent");
            }
          })
          .on("click", function () {
            $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
          })
        $buttons.append($button);
      });

      $("body").append($buttons);

      $("#done").on("click", clearColor);

      function clearColor() {
         $(".buttons").css({backgroundColor:'transparent'});
         $(".buttons").removeClass('clicked');
      }
```